# Windows 10 IOT equivalent of i2cdetect

Tags: pi-2, i2c, windows-iot

I am trying to troubleshoot an I2C device connected to my Raspberry PI Model B.

The device is giving me the following error:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. Slave address was not acknowledged.`

Googling around it seems that it is a generic error message and means that the device is not working. I'd like to troubleshoot this and a Windows version of i2cdetect would be useful.

Further, should an I2C device, once connected correctly, show up in the devices in the Win10 IOT web interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft have a [short walkthrough](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/I2cTestTool.htm) on achieving this using their premade i2cTestTool.

I took a look over the documentation for the WinIoT device manager. I *think* that i2c devices should show up there, but I can't yet pin down a sentence that definitively says it will.

UPDATE

Per your comment, running the i2cTestTool with the `-list` parameter will not enumerate devices attached to the controller. I *think* that using the `-info` parameter will do that. Alternately, you could run multiple passes of the tool to eliminate non-working addresses.

As a second option, [this thread on the raspberrypi.org forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=120180) includes a C# method, written by user vidalsasoon at 27/09/15 1:46pm, which attempts to write data to each address and returns success or fail on each attempt. This should enumerate all the devices attached to a controller:

```
public async Task<bool> FindI2CAddressesAsync(Func<Message, Task> onMessageReceived)
{
    string aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");

    var i2CDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (i2CDevices.Count == 0)
    {
        await onMessageReceived(new Message("bus not found")).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return false;
    }

    for (byte slaveAddress = 0x00; slaveAddress <= 0x7F; slaveAddress++)
    {
        var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(slaveAddress)
        {
            BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode,
            SharingMode = I2cSharingMode.Shared
        };

        foreach (var i2CDevice in i2CDevices)
        {
            var i2CDeviceDetails = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(i2CDevice.Id, settings).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

            try
            {
                var testCommand = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x0 };
                      i2CDeviceDetails.Read(testCommand);

                await onMessageReceived(new Message($"SlaveAddress: {settings.SlaveAddress:X} SUCCESS \n"));
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                await onMessageReceived(new Message($"SlaveAddress: {settings.SlaveAddress:X} FAILED \n"));
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - do you know if the -list option will show devices attached to the controller, or just tell me that my Pi has an I2C controller - which I already know :)

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question about your answer, but I have ran the code and did find a device, however the loop did not respond to any `slaveAddress`. So could you explain the `0x7F` value of the end of the loop parameter?

Comment: 0x7f is 127. So it loops from 0 to 127 because there can be up to 128 devices to I2c. If anyone wondered like me ;) still have no clue why I can't find a slaveaddress.